# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError with arraylist

Tags: java, class, arraylist, version

I've never seen this error before, I have also never used arrayList before, I am just making this code to find out how it works. I'm mainly trying to write a method that deletes a 2D array element if the next one is equal to it (which is the case with the last two elements) I am compiling and running on the same machine and I have just updated java so I'm running the latest version. I am using Linux Ubuntu 11.10. This is the code:

```
import java.util.*; 

public class Test{
public static void main(String[] args){

    float[][] a = {{304.0f, 2743.0f},
    {304.0f, 2743.0f},
    {304.0f, 2754.0f},
    {304.0f, 2754.0f},
    {325.0f, 2764.0f},
    {346.0f, 2775.0f},
    {367.0f, 2775.0f},
    {367.0f, 2764.0f},
    {367.0f, 2754.0f},
    {356.0f, 2723.0f},
    {325.0f, 2691.0f},
    {304.0f, 2670.0f},
    {304.0f, 2639.0f},
    {356.0f, 2639.0f},
    {377.0f, 2650.0f},
    {377.0f, 2650.0f}};

    foo(a);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
        System.out.println(a[i]);

}

public static float[][] foo(float[][] array){

    List<float[]> al = new ArrayList<float[]>(Arrays.asList(array));

    for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); ++i)
        if (al.get(i)[0] == al.get(i+1)[0] && al.get(i)[1] == al.get(i+1)[1])
            al.remove(i);

    float[][] b = new float[al.size()][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); ++i)
        b[i] = al.get(i);

    return b;
}
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Test : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: Test. Program will exit.
```

also if you can suggest an easier method to do this, I would be very grateful. Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All this means is that your version of `javac.exe` is newer than your version of `java.exe`. The class files `javac.exe` is producing can't be read by this old `java.exe`. Often people have an extra old copy of `java.exe` someplace crazy like `C:\WINDOWS`, left there by a misguided installer. Find it and either delete it or fix your `PATH` such that your newer copy is found first.

Comment: I'm running Linux Ubuntu 11.10 (sorry for not clarifying this). How do I do that?

Comment: Well, `java` and `javac`, then, not `*.exe`, but generally the same idea. Typing `which java` will show you where you're getting `java` from. One likely scenario is that there's a `/usr/bin/java` installed, and it's on your path before the JDK you just installed. Modify PATH in `~/.profile` so `JDK/bin` comes first.

Comment: I finally made it, i'm still a rookie with linux as well, thanks very very much!!